# Looping through validation rules

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I have some validation rules that I am trying to apply to some form fields and am doing this via JSON I am receiving from the database.

To get this information I am grabbing it from a backbone model like so.

```
var rules = this.model.get('Rules');
```

and the information that returns from that looks like this. I get many of these snippets per page.

```
{"required":true,"message":{"required":"Please enter Your Name."},"message_spanish":{"required":"El apellido no puede blanco."}}
```

My goal is to try and filter out the english message if they are english speakers and if they are spanish speakers vice versa. I have this logic working in other places in my app, but for some reason I cannot get the for loop to work.

My for loop looks like this

```
for(var i = 0; i != rules.length; ++i)
{

}
```

and I think my issue is coming from where I am trying to find how many rules there are. From what I am gathering it is grabbing how many characters there are instead of how many rules there are.

I have tried wrapping the info in a `JSON.parse()`, but when I try and find the length of that it crashes my computer.

Comment: You have a single object there, rather than a collection. If you get back many rules, you probably want a Backbone collection, or for the model to at least return an array.

Comment: Why are you using a for-loop on an object? It's not an Array. Does the "Rules" field in the model contain a string or an object as in your example? How do you detect if the user is an English speaker or not?

Comment: @Mironor, I've been trying a bunch of different things. That was just my latest attempt to try and parse this out. The model contains exactly what I posted above, each input has one of those. We have a button that they press and then that sets a variable on the user information to detect the language.

Comment: @codemonkey, I just tried to turn it into a backbone model, but then I cannot get any of the information within the for loop. One of the reasons I was trying to use the for loop was I needed to omit certin data depending what language they  choose.

Comment: If each input has _1_ Rule object, then what exactly are you trying to loop over? You would need to create a Collection of Rule objects for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @codemonkey It's because I was trying to say for each rule I need to remove one of the objects and I could not think of another way to do so. If it's english I need to remove the spanish and vice versa.

Comment: Let me clarify, there are many inputs per page and I have to handle every input on the page at once after the page renders. Each input only has one rule object though.

Comment: Could you add complete/example/simulation of your issue for better understanding of your question?

Comment: @VahanVardanyan How can I include a complete example when what I have is not working? Any additional information I have is just the renaming of the message_spanish to message inside the for loop when they choose spanish so knockout doesn't have a hissy fit.

Comment: @zazvorniki You could provide the view and the model just to add more context. Without seeing the rest of your code, I think what you need to do is find a way to add the Model for each input to your view. So you then iterate over View.Inputs and get the Rule object for each one of those inputs.

Comment: @codemonkey This is the only part of the view that is relevant to this issue. Everything else is just click functions to help the dropdowns work and keyboards pop up. I really do not want to add my entire model to each input because that would crash the browser without a doubt. I just need to be able to loop though these rules and then I have the logic that will take care of the rest, I have that working in several places already.